# Are those $4\times 4$ matrices similar or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

When I was solving problems from linear algebra I ran into two problems which seemed to me very interesting. I solved the first one but have some difficulties with the second one.

**Problem 1:** Are the following matrices similar?

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
7 & -12 & 6 \\
10 & -19 & 10 \\
12 & -24 & 13 
\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

*My solution:* One can show that characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p(\lambda)=-(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+1)$. So eigenvalues are $\{-1,1\}$ with multiplicity $1$ and $2$, respectively. Then I shown that eigenspaces $V_{-1}$ and $V_{1}$ has dimensions $1$ and $2$, respectively. Therefore, the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, i.e. has a basis of eigenvectors where the  matrix of this operator is exactly $B$.

**Problem 2:** Which of the matrices $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & -3\\
1 & 1 & -3 & 1\\
-1 & 3 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$ is similar to matrix $$X=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

**My approach:** This problem is a bit harder than the previous one. I was able to derive that $B$ and $X$ are not similar since $\text{rk} X=3$ and $\text{rk}B=2$ which is contradiction since rank of matrix is invariant under similarity. The book says that $A$ and $X$ are similar. I don't know how to show it.

Also one can show that $X$ is not diagonalizable. But I don't know where to use it. Please help me to solve this problem.

**Remark:** In my book this problem comes before Jordan normal form so you are not allowed to use it. I guess that this problem can be solved in some tricky way because the matrix $X$ has nice form but I don't know how.

Would be very thankful for help!

Comment: Similarity means that they perform the same action, just in different bases. Well, you can see that $v=(1,1,1,1)^T$ is in the kernel of $A$. Then find a vector $v_4$ such that $Av_4=v$. Then find a vector $v_3$ such that $Av_3=v_4$, a vector $v_2$ such that $Av_2=v_3$. And finally a $v_1$ such that $Av_1=v_2$. Note that $Xv=(1,1,1,0)$, $X^2v=(1,1,0,0)$, $X^3v=(1,0,0,0)$ and $X^4v=0$. So, send $v_1$ to $v$, $v_2$ to $Xv$, $v_3$ to $X^2v$ and $v_4$ to $X^3v$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy, to be honest i cannot understand what you are doing. Could you give a separate, more detailed answer? I will appreciate it!

Comment: Just finding a bases in which $A$ and $X$ do the same action. That is what similarity is. So, what $X$ does to the basis $w_1=(1,1,1,1), w_2=(1,1,1,0),w_3=(1,1,0,0),w_4=(1,0,0,0)$ is shift them to the next element of the basis and the last one to $(0,0,0,0)$. So, we find a basis in which $A$ does the same. We start from $v_4=(1,1,1,1)$, which $A$ sends to zero. This will play the role of $w_4$ for $A$. We just need to find $v_3$ such that $Av_3=v_4$, $v_2$ such that $Av_2=v_3$ and $v_1$ such that $Av_1=v_2$.

Comment: The change of basis matrix $B$ for which $B^{-1}AB=X$ will send $w_k$ to $v_k$, for $k=1,2,3,4$. I all the above the vectors are supposed to be columns. I skipped writing the transposes.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy, I still have a difficulty to understand you. How are you proving that $A$ and $X$ are similar? Could you give separate answer (not comment)?

Comment: My last comment tells you how. Now compute the vectors $v_3,v_2,v_1$ from the equations that I wrote. No, I won't write anything in a different place. That doesn't change how much of it you understand.

Comment: $X$ is clearly nilpotent, so it has all eigenvalues equal to 0. If you can prove that  $B$ has a nonzero eigenvalue then you're done.

Comment: @Surb And if you are not able to do that, like it happens with $A$, you get right back at the point where this question is at.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy well, the book asks to find out which of $A$ or $B$ is similar to $X$. So one of them must be. So, you just have to find a nonzero eigenvalue of one of these matrices. Iw ould anyway start with $B-\lambda I$ as it has a much simpler determinant to compute. For such exercises, you should focus on the task. If you you need to solve that for research purpose, use a CAS and prove it afterward with standard (probably lengthy) methods.

Comment: @Surb 'none of them' is a valid answer for a problem. So, only discarding $B$, while it is a start, doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy not in *this* context. "Which of the matrices..." is pretty clear I think.

Comment: @Surb 'None' is a valid answer for 'Which?'. You could get away not really knowing if $A$ is similar or not in those exams that only look at the selection of an answer, but that certainly doesn't mean that you know the actual answer until you know for sure if $A$ is similar or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevertheless, you can mimick the way one finds a Jordan basis.

Check the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is the same as $X$, i.e. $\chi_A(x)=x^4$, so by *Hamilton-Cayley*, we have $A^4=0$., which implies $\ker A^4=K^4$ ($K$ being the base field). If $A$ and $X$ are similar, they have the same *minimal polynomial* (which is a divisor of the characteristic polynomial with the same irreducible factors). Therefore the minimal polynomial of $A$ should be $x^4$, and in this case, we have $A^k\ne 0$ for $k\le 3$.

Determine $\ker A^3$, and take any vector $v\notin\ker A^3$, that $Av\in\ker A^3\smallsetminus\ker A^2$,  $A^2v\in\ker A^2\smallsetminus\ker A$ and last that $A^3v\in\ker A$, i.e. is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $0$.

Then show that $\bigl\{v, Av, A^2v, A^3v\bigr\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors, which means, since we're in dimension $4$, they make up a basis.

Last step, check that in this basis, the matrix of $A$ is precisely $X$.

Comment: I have never studied the Jordan canonical form, but why are you considering powers of $A$? Your answer seems technically very difficult.

Comment: @ZFR They are doing the same that I told you above, but in reverse, which makes it less suitable for computing. The conditions for $v$ here are written as inequalitites, while in linear algebra it is easier to solve equations. So, it is better to start by picking the vector $A^3v$ which is in the kernel. This can be the vector $(1,1,1,1)^t$. Then you find $A^2v$ such that $A(A^2v)=A^3v$, etc.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy, the problem that I cannot understand the motivation: why he taking $v\notin \ker A^3$ that $Av\in \ker A^3-\ker A^2$, ..?

Comment: Because, if $0$ is the only eigenvalue of  $A$, we necessarily have $A^4=0$. If the only eigenvalue were $\lambda$, we would consider the powers of $A-\lambda I$. It can be a bit long, but not really difficult. If th matrices are really similarly, to obtain in a basis the matrix $X$, you have to find $4$ vectors such the each maps on the previous one.

Comment: @ZFR That is only to ensure that the $A^3v$ is not zero. But the ultimate motivation is to note that $X$ and $A$ act in that peculiar 'cyclic' way on two bases. Then similarity is established by sending one of those bases to the other.

Comment: I know that minimal polynomial should divide $x^4$. How did you conclude that it is exactly $x^4$?

Comment: @ZFR Compute $X,X^2,X^3$. None of them vanish while $X^4=0$. You could do the same with $A$, but you don't really need to. If you prove similarity the same will happen with $A$. But the computation of the powers of $X$ is something that everyone should do.

Comment: Because it is the case or $X$ (the powers of $X$ are quite easy to compute)

Comment: @Bernard, but why are you computing powers of $X$ but not of $A$? I am completely lost

Comment: @ZFR You can compute powers of $A$ if you want. You don't have to. The only reason that you are lost is because you have never computed $X^2,X^3$ and $X^4$ in your life. Do it. All problems are solved by experience. This is an experience required to solve this problem. And also compute $X(1,1,1,1)^t, X^2(1,1,1,1)^t,X^3(1,1,1,1)^t$ and $X^4(1,1,1,1)^t$.

Comment: I don't really compute the powers of $X$: I *know* what $X^2, X^3, X^4$ are (without having to use pencil and paper). Do it yourself, it is  really easy and very informative.

Comment: @ZFR I will say whatever I want to say. You have no resource to prevent me from doing otherwise.

Comment: You seem to be missing one point: if these matrices are similar, if $X^4=0$, but not before, the same is true for $A$. So you need to find the equation od $\ker A^3$ to find a vector $v$ which is *not* in this kerne.l

Comment: If it did, $v$ would be in $\ker A^3$ since $A^2(Av)=A^3v$.

Comment: Sorry I have deleted previous message since I got it :) Let me clarify one moment also: 1) how do you know that $\{v,Av,A^2v,A^3v\}$ is linearly independent? 2) Why do we need this?

Comment: @ZFR Because similarity means that two matrices are acting on two bases in the same way. In the basis $v,Av,A^v,A^3v$ the matrix $A$ is acting by sending $v$ to $Av$, $Av$ to $A^2v$, $A^2v$ to $A^3v$ and $A^3v$ to zero. While $X$ is doing the same with the basis $(1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,0),(1,1,0,0),(1,0,0,0)$. The matrix $B$ that gives $B^{-1}AB=X$ will be the matrix that sends the second basis to the first.

Comment: 1) If they're not, consider a linear relation between them, and transform it by $A^3$, taking into account that $A^4=0$ and $A^3v\ne 0$, then by $A^2$, &c. to show successively that all coefficients are $0$. We ned these vectors to show the matrix in this basis is exactly $X$.

Comment: @Bernard, it looks like a magic to be honest :) But I guess that I have got it completely! Anyway I will review all this one more time. Thanks a lot for your patience and help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: 1) So the finding Jordan canonical form and Jordan basis can be done also in this way? 2) Am i right that those problems are much more easier to solve with Jordan CF?

Comment: You're very welcome. Always glad to feel helpful!

Comment: @ZFR Yes, you will get it as soon as you compute. You haven't done it, that is why you still don't understand it. There is no magic in mathematics. Only experience. You are only missing the experience of computing the powers of $X$ and its action on its cyclic vectors.

Comment: @ZFR All Jordan form is about is doing this 'cyclic vector' computation but instead of with $A$, with $A-\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. So, it is not that Jordan makes it easier, but that Jordan **is** the computations I told you to do above.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy, Thanks a lot also for your help! I am learning linear algebra just for one month and maybe less. But want to learn it!

Comment: 1) Yes, but  it is a bit complex when there are several eigenvalues (with multiplicity) 2)Not really: to find the Jordan canonical form, you still have to compute the powers of the matrix. But knowing it helps in elaborating a strategy.

Comment: @ZFR Clarification, there is a difference between computing powers of a matrix and solving a system $(A-\lambda)v_{k}=v_{k+1}$ several times, for given vectors $v_{k+1}$ and unknown $v_k$. The later is what you have to do to compute the matrix of transformation to the Jordan form, you don't need to compute powers of a matrix, which is a lot more work.

Comment: I don't agree: in the general case, proceeding backwards if more complex than applying a matrix several times. Furthermore, when the  eigenspace has dimension $>1$, not all eigenvectors can necessarily be lifted up. So how do you know how to choose it?